# redirect to a different html page using angularJs and Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am New to Angularjs and Nodejs. I am trying to call the card.html page after I click on the button using AngularJs. Also, the card.html page should display the "scope.resultCards" obtained back from the controller. How should I achieve the same? Any help/advice would be highly appreciated. Thank you !

My html page looks like this:

```
            <div id ="button_spaces">
            <table> 
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
                    <br>
                    <form action="/card">
                        <td> <input type ="submit" ng-click="getcards(result.setIdNum)" value = {{result.Category}} >
                        </td>
                    </form> 
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Client Controller is as follows:
    $scope.getcards = function(setIdNum) {

```
        var url = "/cards/"+setIdNum;
        console.log(" cards url "+ url);

            $http.get(url).success(function(data){
            $scope.resultCards = data;

            console.log("Test cards: ", $scope.resultCards);
        });
    }
```

and my server.js code is as follows:
    app.get('/cards/:setIdNum', function(req, res) {

```
var searchrequest = req.params.setIdNum;
Cards.find({settIdNum: searchrequest},function(err, found) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        else
        res.json(found); // return all cards in JSON format

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Dipali, Did you need to redirect the page after click ?

Comment: Hi Siva. yes after the button click i need to redirect to another page (card.html) which will display the contents in ( $scope.resultCards )

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state.go` to redirect to another view with param, Refer the official documentation of [UI Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

```
 $scope.getcards = function(setIdNum) {
        var url = "/cards/"+setIdNum;
        console.log(" cards url "+ url);

        $http.get(url).success(function(data){
            $scope.resultCards = data;
            console.log("Test cards: ", $scope.resultCards);
            $state.go("card", { cards: $scope.resultCards });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Siva with your help. I actually resolved it by using $location.path(url).